# Creating a second service pack with WiX

Tags: wix, upgrade

How do you use WiX to create a second service pack for your app?  I’ve released SP1, and that installer works fine.  But I’m having some difficulty with SP2.  My current WiX setup upgrades from the original (RTM) version correctly.  But if I try to upgrade from SP1, the files simply don’t update, although it shows as SP2 in Add/Remove Programs.  What do I need to do to make the upgrade work?  I’ve added another `<TargetImage>`  to  my `<UpgradeImage>`  Other than that, I’m largely following the example from http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/patch_building.htm changing to the version number from 1 to 2.

What changes should I be making for SP2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my error.  I had changed the value of `PatchFamily` (under `<PatchSequence>`).  This caused it to think of SP1 and SP2 as two different "families", so SP2 did not override SP1, even though it had a higher number.  I changed `PatchFamily` to its old value and my patch built successfully.